# How does Google keeps you connected across multiple applications?

Tags: authentication, google-authentication

I wondered what method was used by Google to keep users connected across multiple apps (mail, drive etc..). If I was to guess, I'd say it has to do with the token generated upon connection that is then stored in a database and its existence is checked by the app as it would only be destroyed upon disconnection.

I ask that question for a simple reason: I need to pass data between two websites, as well as stay connected even when the website is closed if the user hasn't signed out. Knowing how Google does would solve both my issues (would allow me to get access to two items I need, user mail and a unrelated name both generated from one site and used by the other).

Answer (score 0):

You can use - cookies. Cookies can be shared with subdomains.

- So on main domain site you will login and store cookies and on another subdomain sites you can use the cookies of main domain site from local storage.

see an example here - how it works. [edeXa Accounts](https://accounts.edexa.com/)